# Creating a read more button and hide words based on word count

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code below that has a `tab` consisting of data from my multidimensional array the problem is i'm trying to create a `read more button` that will show a specific number of words and when i click a `read more button` it will show the rest of the paragraph is there any easy way to do this with javascript and jquery any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

var personArr = [];
var person = {["first-Name"]:"John", ["last-Name"]:"Doe", ["age"]:21, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket.Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket."};
var person2 = {["first-Name"]:"Paul", ["last-Name"]:"Logan", ["age"]:22, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket.Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket."};
var person3 = {["first-Name"]:"Sean", ["last-Name"]:"Kim", ["age"]:32, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket.Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket."};
var person4 = {["first-Name"]:"Ken", ["last-Name"]:"Chow", ["age"]:12, ["person-desc"]:"Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket.Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. Jerky pork loin ham, pork turducken ham hock meatball picanha doner capicola. Landjaeger shank tongue, tri-tip jerky pork chop cupim sausage. Tongue bresaola pastrami turkey shankle chicken pork loin biltong ham hock tenderloin shank brisket."};

personArr.push(person, person2, person3, person4);
console.log(personArr);

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

// Iterate through the Person Array
personArr.forEach((person,i) => {
   // `person` is the ith member of personArr
   var name = document.createElement('h4');
   var desc = document.createElement('p');
   // Update the contents of your h3 element and add it to the fragment.
   name.textContent = ` ${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`;
   desc.textContent = ` ${person['person-desc']}`;
   frag.appendChild(name);
   frag.appendChild(desc);

});
// Add the fragment to the parent :)
parent.appendChild(frag);
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
.line1{
display:inline-block;
}
.size{
width:70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<div class ="size">
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People</button>
</div>

<div id="People" class="tabcontent">
<div class="line1"> 

 </div>
 </div>
</div>


     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the readmore js and try to use this.

https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js